# Linking to boost unit test framework with boost build

Tags: python, boost, build, testing, bjam

Using boost build, if I can link to a boost python library with this in my jamfile:

> project myProject : requirement 
>                        
>                       /boost/python//boost_python ;

how can I link to boost test? I have built the boost test library.

I don't want to use file paths since my code is portable. Thanks

Si

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have standard (or prebuilt) libraries installed in a location which can vary between different machines, you may consider using site-config.  Then the site-config can be adapted on each machine but the project Jamfile remains the same.

See the [Boost Build documentation: Targets in site-config.jam](http://www.boost.org/boost-build2/doc/html/bbv2/recipies/site-config.html) for details.